# Where are the iOS Device icons located?

Tags: cocoa, icons, itunes

When connecting an iOS device iTunes always shows the correct device icon. 
Where are these icons located?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X look in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/` for `icns` files starting with `com.apple`.

Not an "official" source so don't use this in a Mac App Store app.

Answer (score 1):

They are in /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/DeviceIcons.rsrc

but I don't find RSRC editor for 10.x INTEL... anyways, I don't think you should just take apple's icons ;) [im no lawyer though]

Comment: On the desktop the icons also match with the model. I suppose finder is not using itunes.app - maybe there is another source?

Comment: in your question you speak of itunes only. Sure they are also somewhere else. I'd use fseventer or just go though all icns files